# Get the id of a parent element by a sub-child value of Json response using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I have following groovy script to get the values from the response.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

def response = context.expand( '${GetLoansList#Response}' ).toString()
log.info(response)

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText response

log.info(json.items.id)
```

my json response is similar to this

```
{
"items" : [
  {
     "id" : 48223,
     "name" : "LAI-00151007",
     "amount" : 25050.0,
     "interest_rate" : 25.99,
     "term" : 60,
  },
  {
     "id" : 48262,
     "name" : "LAI-00152581",
     "amount" : 44225.0,
     "interest_rate" : 18.9,
     "term" : 36,
  },
 ],
 "total_count" : 13
 }
```

I want to get the corresponding 'id' for the given name ("name": "LAI-00152581",). What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
json.items.find({ it.name == "LAI-00152581" })?.id
```

`?.` is for safety when there is no `items` meeting the criteria. In which case the result will be `null`

Since Groovy 2.5.0 there is one more way of doing this, which is semantically equivalent:

```
json.items.findResult { if (it.name == "LAI-00152581") return it.id }
```